# Interesting inequalities

Tags: inequality, summation, radicals, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ be nonnegativ real numbers.

(a) Prove that if $x_1x_2\dots x_n=1$, then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{n-1+x_i}\leq 1$$

(b) Find the maximum value of $$\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\frac{n}{x_i}-1+x_i^n}$$
where $x_1+x_2+\dots +x_n=n$.

I rewrote the expression:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{1+y_i} \leq n-1$$
where $$y_i=\dfrac{x_i}{n-1}$$

Comment: What is your question, exactly? What did you get when you rewrote the expression, and how is that related to the question?

Answer (score 1):

a) By AM-GM 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n-1+x_i}=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac{x_i}{x_i+n-1}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{n}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{x_i+(n-1)\sqrt[n]{\prod\limits_{k=1}^nx_k}}=$$
$$=\frac{n}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sqrt[n]{x_i^{n-1}}}{\sqrt[n]{x_i^{n-1}}+(n-1)\sqrt[n]{\prod\limits_{k\neq i}x_k}}\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{n}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sqrt[n]{x_i^{n-1}}}{\sqrt[n]{x_i^{n-1}}+\sum\limits_{k\neq i}\sqrt[n]{x_k^{n-1}}}=\frac{n}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n-1}\cdot1=1.$$

b) By AM-GM
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\frac{n}{x_i}+x_i^n-1}\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt[n+1]{\left(\frac{1}{x_i}\right)^n\cdot x_i^n}-1}=1.$$
The equality occurs when all $x_i=1$, which says that $1$ is a maximal value.